# Squares and Subprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For any prime $p$, let $S_p$ denote the finite set of odd primes $q$ less than or equal to $p$. For instance, $S_{11} = \{3,5,7,11\}$.

Let $C_p$ be the product of all the primes in $S_p$.

**Definition:**  An odd integer a is *subprime* with respect to the prime $p$ if $a$ is relatively prime to all primes in $S_p$. Namely, if $a$ is *subprime* to $p$, then the condition $(a,q) = 1$ holds for all $q\in S_p$.

**Example:** $133$ is subprime with respect to 5 as it is not divisible by 3 or 5 but not subprime with respect to 7.

Fix a prime $p$ and an even integer $e$. Let $m$ be the largest **odd** number less than $\frac{p^2}2$. Consider the set
$$T(p,e) =\{1^2 - e, 3^2 - e,5^2 - e,\cdots, m^2 - e\}.$$

The main question is whether each set $T(p,e)$ contains an element which is *subprime* with respect to $p$.

Example: Let $p = 5$ and $e=214$.
The odd integers which are less than 25/2 are {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11} and so $m=11$.

The set $$T(5,214) =\{1^2 - 214, 3^2 - 214, 5^2 - 214, 7^2-214, 9^2-214,11^2 - 214\}$$ is
$$ \{-213, -205, -189, -165, -133, -93\}.$$

Here $-133$ is subprime with respect to $p=5$.

**Main Question:** For each even integer $e$ in the range $$-2C_p \le e \le 2C_p,$$ does $T(p,e)$ contain an element which is subprime with respect to $p$?

Comment: The property described here has a name : The $y$-rough numbers which are the positive integers have no factor below $y$ (Since you only look at odd numbers this is the same property). For large $x$ and $y$, we can estimate how many positive integers below $x$ are $y$-rough.